# Can't rewrite URL in a directory

Tags: regex, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite

So here's my regex

```
Options -MultiViews
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^article/([0-9]+)$ article.php?id=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
RewriteRule ^site/(.*)$ site.php?id=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /$1.php [L]
```

And this is what I want my URL to look like:

```
http://localhost/developer/site/google.com
```

So I'd do

```
RewriteRule ^site/(.*)$ site.php?id=$1 [L]
```

But when I go to the URL all I get is

> Not Found
>
> The requested URL /developer/site/google.com was not found on this server.

Even though I have an `site.php` in my `developer` folder. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use a correct path for your rewrite (`RewriteBase`) assuming your htaccess is in `developer` folder.

Also, please don't forget that `RewriteCond` are for next `RewriteRule` **only**.

```
Options -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /developer/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^article/([0-9]+)$ article.php?id=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^site/([^/]+)$ site.php?id=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/developer/$1\.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```